# Ignore errors on recursive search

Tags: powershell

This is my command on Windows 10:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-ChildItem -Path "\\sharename\path1\engineering" -Recurse > file_data.txt
```

And this is my output:

```
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path '\\sharename\path1\engineering\Litigation
Images\nsharma\A - Investments documents\Wall Street, finance and related\Education, conferences, and
seminars\Back-office, fund accounting, related\AMF Workshop on Fails Management and Resolution_files'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path "\\sharename\path1\engineering" -R ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\sharename\path1\...esolution_files:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I can see in the output file file_data.txt that nothing was returned after the file/path that caused the error.

I want to retrieve all the possible files that won't error, I'll deal with the errors later.  As it stands now, the searching stops at the first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it as simple as adding

```
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

to the end of your line? I would have added this as a comment but I can't...